# Is there an elegant way to allow Android Screen Readers to respect changes to aria-hidden on Chrome?

Tags: android, html, google-chrome, accessibility, screen-readers

When using Android Screen Reader to navigate a webpage on Chrome, elements that are aria-hidden do not work correctly if the aria-hidden value changes during the lifespan of the page.

For example, if the value of aria-hidden changes from false to true, the element will still be in the accessibility order.

**Sidenote**: Sometimes, after looping through the now aria-hidden element once, it will correctly hide the next time through. This is how I was able to conclude that this issue is with Chrome specifically.

These changes however, are respected correctly using Samsung Browser on Samsung devices.

Through experimentation, I found that setting the element's display to none briefly and then reverting the change causes the new value of aria-hidden to be respected. This leads me to believe that Chrome might be performing some kind of micro-optimization where it ignores aria-hidden changes. However, this is visually inconvenient since the user will notice the flicker as the element is hidden and re-displayed. Does anyone know of a better way to resolve this?

Here is a stackblitz if anyone wants to see it in action:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/aria-hidden-test
After 3 seconds, the outlined boxes will be aria-hidden.

Simply navigate to the webpage on chrome on android and turn voiceover on (Use default settings).

Comment: what are you actually trying to achieve? I am hesitant to suggest a fix for something that could be abused and make it so that screen reader users experience a different page to sighted users after it loads. Why would you programatically hide a section from a screen reader but not make any other changes to the page? If you update the CSS at the same time I would suspect this works fine, as your example shows, I also suspect it works with `display: hidden` and maybe even `opacity: 0` - `aria-hidden` should never be changed in isolation from a visual change. Hide it before initial render.

Comment: An example scenario is if an alert dialog pops up on the page. Since it doesn't completely fill the page, I cannot simply hide the content because it's still visible on the page. Aria-hidden is an easy solution that works well on Safari. Using focus events, I can create a focus trap so that it works on web browsers on desktop. However, it doesn't work with Android screen readers.